# How to extract part of protein complex separated with HEADER with two molecules from one PDB file

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics, pdb

I have a PDB file which contain two molecules (receptor and ligand).
Each molecule will have its own header. All in **ONE** PDB file.

‌The header of receptor section looks like this (line 1-6 of the PDB file):

```
HEADER rec.pdb
REMARK original generated coordinate pdb file
ATOM      1  N   GLY A   1     -51.221 -13.970  37.091  1.00  0.00      RA0  N
ATOM      2  H   GLY A   1     -50.383 -13.584  37.482  1.00  0.00      RA0  H
ATOM      3  CA  GLY A   1     -50.902 -15.071  36.197  1.00  0.00      RA0  C
ATOM      4  C   GLY A   1     -49.525 -15.659  36.443  1.00  0.00      RA0  C
```

and this ligand section (line   11435 to 11440) of the PDB file

```
HEADER lig.000.00.pdb
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      27.318 -26.957  12.663  1.00  0.00      LA0  N
ATOM      2  H   MET A   1      27.313 -27.570  11.870  1.00  0.00      LA0  H
ATOM      3  CA  MET A   1      28.374 -27.102  13.668  1.00  0.00      LA0  C
ATOM      4  CB  MET A   1      28.531 -28.564  14.090  1.00  0.00      LA0  C
ATOM      5  CG  MET A   1      27.224 -29.154  14.628  1.00  0.00      LA0  C
```

Note that the receptor and ligand section also contain the string `RA0` and `LA0`
at the 11th column of PDB file.

What I want to do is to rename the chain of receptor as chain A and ligand as chain B.
In order to do that I intended to extract both part into two different objects first,
then rename the chain and finally put them together again.

I tried this code with [Bio3D](http://thegrantlab.org/bio3d/).
But doesn't work:

```
library(bio3d)
pdb_infile <- "myfile.pdb"

pdb <- read.pdb(pdb_infile)
receptor_segment.sele <- atom.select(pdb, segid = "RA0",  verbose = TRUE)
receptor_pdb <- trim.pdb(pdb, receptor_segment.sele)
ligand_segment.sele <- atom.select(pdb, segid = "LA0",  verbose = TRUE)
ligand_pdb <- trim.pdb(pdb, ligand_segment.sele) # showed no entry
```

What's the way to do it?
I'm open to solution with R or Python.